# How to block or ignore Real Name requests?

Tags: psn, ps4

One of the PS4's most annoying features in my opinion, is the Real Name Request. I don't want to share my real name over PSN nor do I care about other people's real name, yet I frequently receive them - sometimes from the same people who probably forgot they sent me one already - and I'm getting tired of deleting them all the time.

I know [I can edit my real name over the PS4](http://www.ps4mouse.com/how-to-hide-real-name-on-ps4-online-and-local/) and have set it to "Name withheld", but that doesn't actually solve my problem. I could just Let everybody see my "real name", but I'm concerned some people might believe my real name is indeed "Name withheld".

Since the PS4 offers an option to block Friend Requests, I guess there might also be one to block Real Name Requests but I haven't had any luck finding it. Does anybody know how to block or ignore those annoying requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't. Those requests are often because it is the first option in the profile view and most people just press it without noticing, probably want to do something else. Bear with it, or just show the initials or something.

Comment: Actually, using my initial instead of "Name withheld" might be a good compromise. I think I'll just do that, thanks.